# Hand written move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, memcpy

I have written a vector class to learn move semantics.
I use move constructor to move T (commented line).

My question is why not to just copy all the bytes of temp object and set all bytes of temp object to zero like in C?

I know that the destructor will be called for temp object and it may require some initialized members to properly destruct. This can be reason why I must not change internal representation of the object.

But in case I'm 100% sure my ~T() don't have such requirements, is this a good optimization?

```
 20     void push_back(T&& val)
 21     {
 22         check_cap();
 23         //new (m_data + m_size) T(std::move(val));
 24         for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i)
 25         {
 26             reinterpret_cast<char*> (m_data + m_size)[i] = reinterpret_cast<char*> (&val)[i];
 27             reinterpret_cast<char*> (&val)[i] = 0;
 28         }
 29         m_size++;
 30     }
```

**(please don't tell anything about casts and their safety if it's not related to the actual question)**

**(I know it's not a good approach and better not to use it in real project. But I'm only interested how good is it from the point of efficiency.)**

Comment: You will find plenty of questions here on stackoverflow.com from people wondering why after they `memcpy` their C++ objects, from here to there, all hell breaks loose. Which is what effectively ends up happening here. This is only going to end in tears. You cannot expect to simply copy a C++ object, byte by byte, and everyone will live happily ever after. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: You can mem-copy memory representation only for _trivially-copyable_ types. Once a type has a user-provided move constructor, it's no longer trivially copyable.

Comment: Did you try measuring both versions to see what the difference is?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but you need to understand that this question is close to invalid. Asking about the performance of something that is likely to not work is pretty pointless. If you care about **very** specific circumstances, you can always inspect the generated assembly. We don't know which specific circumstances are of interest to you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you please explain in more details?

Comment: Sure. Here's a simple example. A typical `std::string` is a pointer and a size of the string. You just byte-by-byte copied it. Great! And now you have two `std::string`s pointing to the same internal buffer, and both of their destructors will (eventually) attempt to `delete[]` the same exact, bleeping pointer. Hillarity ensues. Now you have a mysterious crash and memory corruption in completely unrelated part of your code, forcing you to write another post on Stackoverflow, wondering what's up with that? So, how more "efficient" than proper move semantics did this turn out to be, in the end?

Comment: You can always check the generated assembly. For example, in my experiment, it was practically the same for move-constructor and byte-copying cases: https://godbolt.org/z/cTs8z4 (I don't care about UB here since you seem not to care as well ;-).

Comment: If your class `T` can be copied by copying all its bytes, then what is the point of a move constructor? Copying all the bytes and setting the RHS to zero is **less** efficient than a normal copy constructor which wouldn't need to touch the RHS.

Comment: You might like following article about a proposal for the c++ standard: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/09/28/trivially-relocatable-vs-destructive-movable/

Comment: This question implies a lack of understanding of what movement in C++ is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why not to just copy all the bytes of temp object and set all bytes of temp object to zero like in C?
>
> is this a good optimization?

I think not. Here's a [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/i0Iv09nb3J6Pp73HgCX9Jo7EYhY) comparison between your hand written version and the normal version using `clang++`:

[image]

When using `g++` the result is [a tie](https://quick-bench.com/q/U5lD3oD9IpZ5DSRPYBuxkVoXb0A), so no gain there either.

Comment: To nitpick - the element must be inserted via placement new `new(m_data+m_size) T(std::move(val));`, not `operator=`. But it does not change the benchmark.

Comment: What is weird is that in `Normal`, the compiler issues SSE instructions, while for `HandWritten`, it does not. The same when I used `memcpy`/`memset` instead of the manual loop. In my above-mentioned experiment (https://godbolt.org/z/cTs8z4), GCC behaved the same until I provided `-mavx` flag explicitly.

Comment: @Quimby Perhaps. I used `new T[...];` so the elements are there already, ready to be move assigned to.

Comment: @DanielLangr Interesting. Perhaps a diff in compilers? clang 10 vs gcc 10.2?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Clang resulted in the same SSE-based assembly just with `-O2`: https://godbolt.org/z/TxTo94. Don't know why it did not inside quick-bench.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, did not noticed that, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Your plan is a bad one.

Compilers can, using [the as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), often work out that a memcpy and a zero - or even just skipping the destructor - is legal.

If such a compiler runs into your hand crafted undefined behaviour, it either gets confused by the undefined behaviour or becomes unable to further optimize because of it.

---

There are sometimes good reasons to resort to undefined behaviour.  But they **start with proving your solution makes things better**, and exhausting the standard compliant solutions.  And they end with a frank discussion of the real short, medium and long term risks, in exchange for only a short term guaranteed benefit.

Your case does none of this.

Optimizing move-destroy to memcpy is something compilers already do with types that are easy to understand in simple code flow.  Doing it manually is 99/100 pointless and 90/100 times harmful.

If your types are not simple and the code flow easy to understand, then probably your optimization is also difficult to prove safe.  And if you simplify your types and code flow, by the time you can reliably prove your memcpy zero is optimal, your compiler probably can as well.

Sit down with godbolt and play with the optimized compiler output.  It is educational.

Answer (score 2):

Your optimization can be valid for a few cases. It can cause issues when your move constructor does something specific.

```
 class MyCustomClass : public IObserver
 {
     Registry &registry;
     // ...
 public:
     MyCustomClass(MyCustomClass &&rhs)
     : registry{rhs.registry}
     {
          registry.register(*this);
     }
     // ...
 };
```

If you do a bitwise copy of this class the moved instance ain't registered with the registry.

By zeroing out, the reference gets corrupted and the destructor of the original instance will most likely crash on deregistering from the registry.